# Django Postgres Tests, Set DB encoding

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-testing

My Django tests are failing with this error.

```
DatabaseError: character 0xcb88 of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"
```

It's because the encoding on the database needs to be UTF8. However this is the test database created automatically by Django.

How can I tell it to create it with the correct encoding?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define charset for test database in your settings.py file: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEST_CHARSET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEST_CHARSET)